# Database Model's meta data should be defined in models file or migration file?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, model, sequelize.js

Using `sequelize init` I generated a model with a migration.

Inside model.js there is only the definition of the type of each attribute, e.g.

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
```

In migration file, there are additional options e.g.

```
...
up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
...
```

If for example I want to make email unique, I would change the email attribute to:

```
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true
      },
```

My question is whether is a good or bad idea to also include those extra options of attributes inside model.js file or just keep it simple by keeping only the definitions of the attributes (the `types`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes , you can do it and also you can define validation for the value like this .

so , you don't have to find every time that `email_id` is already exits or not in api call .

```
email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING(18),
      validate: {
        isUnique(value, next) {
          user.find({
            where: { email: value },
            attributes: ['id']
          }).done((user) => {
            if (user)
              return next('errors.email.unique');

            next();
          });
        }
      }
```